# I tried using s_client (openssl) and the javax.net.ssl package to connect to encrypted socket

Tags: sockets, ssl, openssl

I tried using s_client (openssl) and the javax.net.ssl package to connect to encrypted socket.

s_client works but probably not on non-rooted android, that is why i tried the javax.net.ssl package but i get the following error:

java.net.SocketException: Socket has been closed or broken

Also, what is "NaiveTrustManager()"? (https://github.com/maruohon/JavaIRC)

```
package SSLSocketClient;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.net.ssl.*;
public class SSLSocketClient{
public static void main(String[] args) {
SSLSocketFactory f = 
(SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
  try {
     SSLSocket s =
       (SSLSocket) f.createSocket("localhost", 6697);

     s.startHandshake();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new 
InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new 
OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(
s.getInputStream()));

String line;

while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(line);
}

s.close();


  } catch (IOException e) {
     System.err.println(e.toString());
  }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by Accepting Self-Signed SSL Certificates in Java..

http://howardism.org/Technical/Java/SelfSignedCerts.html

Comment: This is not "solved" but "worked around" in an insecure way. Without proper certificate validation you don't know if you talk to the expected server or some man in the middle attacker. And if you had a closer look at the output of `openssl s_client` you would likely see that it failed to verify the certificate too, only that it does not disconnect in this case since it is just a test tool.

Comment: You have not really solved anything, you are mostly now at the same level of security as plain text, accepting to connect in fact to any host so sending encrypted content to unkwown sources.